# Probability of getting exactly two dices showing a "one" none of the times during n trials

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, dice

**My problem**:

> We repeat event A five times independently.
> `Event A:` We throw four dices.
> What is the probability that we get exactly two dices showing a **"one"** none of the five times?

**The answer**:
P(exactly ⚀⚀ none of the five times) = 0.54

**My attempt of solving the problem**:
P(exactly ⚀⚀ none of the five times) = 1 - P(exactly ⚀⚀ all of the times)
P(exactly ⚀⚀ one time) = (1/6)(1/6)(5/6)(5/6) = (25/1296) = 0.0193
P(exactly ⚀⚀ all of the times) = (25/1296)<sup>5</sup> = 2.67100706*10<sup>-9</sup>

P(exactly ⚀⚀ none of the five times) = 1-2.67100706*10<sup>-9</sup> = 0.99999999732

**My Question**:
I don't get the correct answer, what am I doing wrong? I am very thankful for any help and/or guidance.

Comment: The first line in your attempt is wrong. P(two die showing 1, none of the time)=1-P(two die showing 1, at least 1 time).

Comment: Standard rant: "dices" is a verb meaning "cuts into small cubes".  "Dice" without the "s" on the end is already the plural of the singular "die".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the counter-probability: The counter event is "At least one times we get 1-1", which is more likely than getting "1-1 all five times".

Anyway, I wouldn't use the counter-probability, it's easier to calculate the probability directly:

Of the $6^4$ possibilities we have $\binom{4}{2} \cdot 5^2$ possibilities of having exactly two dice with a $4$: $\binom 4 2$ is needed to choose the two dices that gave a $1$ and the $5^2$ is necessary to get the other possible numbers (besides $1$). Therefore we have:

$$
P(\text{exactly 1-1 none of the five times}) = \left(1-\frac{\binom 4 2 \cdot 5^2}{6^4}\right)^5 \approx 0.884^5 \approx 0.54
$$